# ORA-03150: end-of-file on communication channel for database link

Tags: sql, oracle, exception, database-link

In an Oracle database there's a big PL/SQL procedure being executed periodically that copies data from one DB to another one through a database link and it is failing after some hours with the following error:

```
ORA-03150: end-of-file on communication channel for database link 
ORA-02063: preceding line from DBPREMOTE 
ORA-06512: at "DBLOCAL.JOB_NAME", line 710 
...
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Line 710 is the first line of a procedure:

```
 execute immediate 'set constraints all deferred';
```

Then the procedure does some inserts and updates, which I guess are failing at some point due to PK, data not valid or whatever other reason. I guess that the exception is being pointing at that line because it is the first one, not because it is actually failing there, but I don't know for sure the real exception.

Is there any chance I can get the real exception so I can handle it?

Comment: It's more likely that you've got a slightly flaky network than an INSERT failing. If the INSERT was failing you'd still get an error related to that (you can test this - don't assume!)

Comment: It's a distributed transaction, so the first step is to look for more details in the `alert.log` on **the remote server**. That should give you enough information to understand why the transaction failed.

Comment: We just received the alert.log details and we are getting:

`TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 505
    
TNS-00505: Operation timed out
    nt secondary err code: 110
    nt OS err code: 0` in the local DB, nothing in the alert.log of the remote server. So we are inclined to think that it is something in the local procedure. I guess the timeout after 2h is normal.

Comment: Can it be that `execute immediate 'set constraints all deferred';` is taking longer than the timeout?

Answer (score 0):

A potential workaround could be to close the DB-Link after **each** usage with a PL/SQL procedure like this:

```
FOR aLink IN (SELECT * FROM V$DBLINK) LOOP
    DBMS_SESSION.CLOSE_DATABASE_LINK(aLink.DB_LINK);
END LOOP;
```

or

```
DECLARE
    DATABASE_LINK_IS_NOT_OPEN EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(DATABASE_LINK_IS_NOT_OPEN, -2081);
BEGIN
    DBMS_SESSION.CLOSE_DATABASE_LINK('DBPREMOTE ');
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN DATABASE_LINK_IS_NOT_OPEN THEN 
        NULL;
END;
```

If the connections are dropped anyway, you should talk to your network guys. Perhaps they drop the connection by firewall settings. However, there could be many others reasons.

Comment: Yes, the problem is a connection timeout, which would be fixed with this workaround but something is making the procedure to be so slow to let the link timeout.